# Shadow rectangles for matrix representation in 3d

Tags: matrices, 3d

I have tried all the tex forums as well as texwelt.de however I could not find a simple way to draw the following in latex.

Any ideas folks?

[image]

Update: I have reached thus far.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=(15:.5cm), y=(90:.5cm), z=(330:.5cm), >=stealth]

\foreach \z in {5,8} 
\foreach \x in {0,...,1}
\foreach \y [evaluate={\b=random(0, 1);}] in {0,...,3}
\filldraw [fill=none] (\x, \y, \z) -- (\x+1, \y, \z) -- (\x+1, \y+1, \z) --
(\x, \y+1, \z) -- cycle (\x+.5, \y+.5, \z) node [yslant=tan(15)] {\b};      

\draw (0, 0, 5) -- (0, 0, 8); 
\draw (2, 0, 5) -- (2, 0, 8);
\draw [dashed] (0, 4, 5) -- (0, 4, 8);
\draw [dashed] (2, 4, 5) -- (2, 4, 8);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe using `TikZ`?

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? Right now, this is just a do-it-all-for-me. You may get lucky, but the picture isn't cute and lacks ducks, so you may not. You'll stand more chance of getting help if you post some code, preferably a complete, minimal document showing what you've tried. Looks pretty simple with Ti*k*Z. No need for 3D here.

Comment: hello @cfr posted the code. Suggest any ideas if you have. I hope it will be helpful to others venturing into latex.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, possibly?

[image: 3D (fake) matrices/matrix]

I started from your code, but I used `tikz-3dplot` to do the calculations for me. We draw two matrices: one on the `background` layer and one on the `main` layer (which is default). The shaded sidings are also placed on in the background.

It might have been helpful to describe this diagram a bit more. I did several things I didn't need to do, just because it was not obvious what was going on.

The matrices are named, so that the nodes inside them can be used to define the areas which should be shaded on the sides. The background one is `b`; the other `f`. So the loops join `b-1-1` to `f-1-1` and so on for all the cells. We skip a column in the middle of each so that the two vertical columns have something like the target separation. A thick `line width` with `draw opacity=0` is used to create the smaller horizontal gaps. (You could also fiddle with row and column separations, if you prefer - see the Ti*k*Z manual.)

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}%
\newlength\mylength\settowidth\mylength{\Large$99$}\newlength\mywidth\settototalheight\mywidth{\Large$99$}\ifdim\mywidth>\mylength\setlength\mylength{\mywidth}\fi
\tikzset{%
  my matrix/.style={%
    matrix of math nodes,
    nodes={line width=2.5pt, fill opacity=.85, font=\Large, text width=\mylength, text centered, text height=\mylength, text depth=0mm, draw, draw opacity=0, text opacity=1, fill=#1 }
  }
}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    tdplot_main_coords,
  ]
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \matrix (b) [my matrix=black!75] at (-1,0,0) { 7 && 8 \\ 9 && 10 \\ 11 && 12\\};
  \end{scope}
    \matrix (f) [my matrix=gray!10] at (0,0,0) { 1 && 2 \\ 3 && 4 \\ 5 && 6\\};
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \foreach \i in {3,1} \foreach \j in {3,2,1} \foreach \k/\m/\n/\l in {south west/north west/45/-45,south east/north east/135/-135} \fill [gray!20, fill opacity=.5] ([shift=(\n:1.25pt)]f-\j-\i.\k) -- ([shift=(\n:1.25pt)]b-\j-\i.\k) -- ([shift=(\l:1.25pt)]b-\j-\i.\m) -- ([shift=(\l:1.25pt)]f-\j-\i.\m) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is excellent @cfr thank you. Hope it is useful for someone. Basically what it does, it display the matrix array of numpy visually.